# Breakpoint in function in different file

Tags: perl, debugging

I have two Perl files like this. Using perl5db.pl I am trying to set a breakpoint at line 7 in file2.pl but sadly it doesn't let me. I looked for answers, and found that I can use modules, but file2.pl isn't using modules. What can I do?

```
#file.pl is
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
require "file2.pl";

#  This file is a test file to run the debugger on.

hello();
my $var = 1;
my $var2 = 2;
makeEqual();
sub main {
  if($var == $var2){
    print "they are equal\n";
  }
  else {
    print "they are not equal\n";
    makeEqual();
  }
  my $value =2;
  print "the value is $value\n";

}

sub makeEqual {
  $var = $var2;
  my $str = "  this is crazy";
  $str =~ s/\s+/ /g;
  print "$str is done \n";
}
main();
```

---

```
#file2.pl is

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub hello {
  print "I am in hello";
}
1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after init your debugger set a breakpoint to stop after compiling your function of `file2.pl`, and when the debugger stops at that point, the return statement (instruction `1;`) you will be able to see the `hello` function of that file.

Execute the debugger:

```
perl -d file.pl
```

Stop when function `hello` is compiled:

```
DB<1> b compile hello
```

Continue:

```
DB<2> c
```

Now function `hello` exists so set a breakpoint in it and continue:

```
DB<2> b hello
DB<3> c
```

Now you are there:

```
main::hello(file2.pl:7):      print "I am in hello";
```

Comment: can i replace require with use?

Comment: i want to so i don't have to compile everytime but, i don't understand module, what would be the module of file2.pl...its in the same directory as the previous one...thanks